# Debezium connector for MySQL. The db history topic is missing

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect, debezium

I'm using the Debezium connector version 0.8 to capture the changes from a MySQL database and move it to Kafka. I'm using Docker with a container for MySQL, another one for the connector, and another one for Kafka.

When I stop Docker (`docker-compose down`) and I start Docker one more time, I usually get the following error:

```
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.ConnectException: The db history topic is missing. You may attempt to recover it by reconfiguring the connector to SCHEMA_ONLY_RECOVERY
```

I have read the solution for this issue on the official page here:

https://debezium.io/blog/2018/03/16/note-on-database-history-topic-configuration/

But I followed those steps and I think my configuration is ok:

```
log.retention.bytes = -1
log.retention.hours = 168       
log.retention.minutes = null
log.retention.ms = -1
```

Note that if I set `log.retention.ms` to -1 then `log.retention.minutes` and `log.retention.hours` won't be used like the official documentation explains, and then I have solved the retention size and retention time problems.

So, does anybody know why I'm getting this error?

This is a part of university work. I think I cannot share the complete `docker-compose` file before I publish it at my university, but I can show you the important things related to this problem. I don't think this is a configuration problem because I have nothing special in my `docker-compose`.

```
mysql:
    image: mysql/5.7:configured (Little changes like enabling queries...)
environment:
     - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=debezium
     - MYSQL_USER=mysqluser
     - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mysqlpw
    volumes:
     - "sql_Data:/var/lib/mysql"
     - "sql_LogError:/var/log/mysql"

kafka:
    image: debezium/kafka:0.8
    depends_on:
     - zookeeper
    environment:
     - HOST_NAME=xxxx
     - ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=xxxx
     - ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT=zookeeper:2181
     - KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS="events:1:1"
     - KAFKA_LOG_RETENTION_MS=-1
    volumes:
          - "kafka_Data:/kafka/data" 
          - "kafka_Log:/kafka/logs"
          - "kafka_Conf:/kafka/config"

connect:
    image: debezium/connect:0.8
    depends_on:
     - zookeeper
     - kafka
     - mysql
    environment:
     - HOST_NAME=xxxx
     - ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME=xxxx
     - BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS=xxxx:9092
     - GROUP_ID=1
     - CONFIG_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_configs
     - OFFSET_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_offsets
     - STATUS_STORAGE_TOPIC=my_connect_statuses
volumes: 
  sql_Data:
  sql_LogError:
  kafka_Data:
  kafka_Log:
  kafka_Conf:
```

And the other parts are only networks or not relevant things.

Comment: What version of Debezium are you using?

Comment: Can you share your Docker Compose file too?

Comment: I've edited the initial post to add the docker-compose part. I hope it's enough info

Comment: Could you please check if a topic with schema history created? If yes, are there data? Could you use `kafka-topics` tool to get metadat information about the topic?

Comment: The dbhistory exists and it has data inside (I monitor it with kafka tool). 

I see if I use docker-compose stop instead of docker-compose down it works ok. It could be maybe a volumes problem but I dont find the problem. I've tried to use the kafka volumes as external but the problem persists. Its possible I need to set more environment variables? I have checked the official documentation about how to create the volumes for this kafka image and I think I have done the correct volumes configuration.

[link](https://github.com/debezium/docker-images/tree/master/kafka/0.8#storing-data)

Comment: I observe when I do docker-compose down and docker-compose up, all the topics related with the mysql database and the dbhistory topic are missing. If I use docker-compose stop/start this problem does not happen but its not a solution.

Comment: @JiriPechanec After thinking a lot about this problem, it's possible this problem arise because of debezium uses for kafka and connect volumes within the Dockerfile? When a new container is (re)created (docker-compose down/up) the new container create new volumes like I noticed and the old info is lost. Please correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @zamora14 You are right that it sounds like an issue with volumes. If you want data to survive destruction o containe then you must map the volume to the host directory. Also make sure that ZooKeeper volumes are mapped too.

Comment: @JiriPechanec Finally, I found the problem: An errata with the volumes in the official debezium/zookeeper documentation. I explain it below.

Comment: @zamora14 Tham yu for tthe finidng - https://issues.jboss.org/browse/DBZ-1231

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after struggling with this problem during a lot of days I found the cause of the problem and the solution.

There is an errata in the documentation of the `debezium/zookeeper` image. As you can see in this link:

[link to debezium/zookeeper image in dockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/r/debezium/zookeeper/)

The documentation establishes 3 volumes to save all the data zookeeper needs. The paths to these volumes are:

1. `/zookeeper/data`
2. `/zookeeper/logs`
3. `/zookeeper/conf`

The problem here is the second one is wrong. According to its `Dockerfile`, the path to the second one, which is used to save the transaction log, must be:

`/zookeeper/txns`

Here is a snippet of its `Dockerfile`.

```
# Expose the ports and set up volumes for the data, transaction log, and configuration
EXPOSE 2181 2888 3888
VOLUME ["/zookeeper/data","/zookeeper/txns","/zookeeper/conf"]
```

Comment: ...and as for the solution?

Answer (score 4):

I faced a similar problem. Your `database.server.id` and `database.server.name` in `mysql.properties` config file need to be unique.

Comment: The problem was an errata in the documentation of the debezium/zookeeper image (I dont know if actually fixed). Read my answer below, maybe it can help you

Comment: Changing the `database.server.name` helped me fix the issue!

Comment: I solved too changing the name of `database.server.name` but this cannot be a valid solution! It's like Debezium/Strimzi/Kafka holds memory of the history topic and, no matter how deep I clean old objects, it refuses to start clean and fires the reported error.

Comment: @Rohan Mudaliar unique with what? do you mean the `database.server.id` cannot equal the `databaser.server.name`? or do you mean that each connector must have it's own unique `database.server.id` and `database.server.name`? or does each debezium instance require a unique `database.server.id` and `database.server.name`? or does each database schema require a unique (...)? or does each rdbms require (...)?

Answer (score 1):

Never let the history topic expire or delete the history topic. This is what causes the issue.

To avoid expiry of the topic, run the following, per the Kafka documentation here: https://debezium.io/blog/2018/03/16/note-on-database-history-topic-configuration/

```
<KAFKA_DIR>/bin/kafka-configs.sh --zookeeper zookeeper:2181 --entity-type topics --entity-name <DB_HISTORY_TOPIC> --alter --add-config retention.bytes=-1
```

To recover from this issue in a development environment, just delete your original connector and recreate a new connector with a different name.

Comment: After I wrote the question I found the solution, it was an errata in the documentation and it was reported issues.jboss.org/browse/DBZ-1231 and I think solved. You can read my answer above to know more about it, but as I say, its still solved.

Answer (score 0):

By changing the name in connector properties file i am passing fixed the error for me. Apparently even though, we delete the topics and all the name has to be unique whenever you restart the connection.